# How on earth can I stop this CUPS-related message on my Debian 6 virtual machine?

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, cups

I’ve got a Debian 6 VMWare virtual machine that I mostly use via SSH (but occasionally via the GUI).

Every few minutes, the following message gets printed in my terminal:

```
CUPS config timestamp change detected but old config retrieved via interface!
```

For a while, I ignored it. Then, I uninstalled CUPS:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove cups
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and restarted. I’m still getting the message.

How on earth can I stop it? I’m never, ever going to want to print from this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah — turns out I think this was actually a VMWare issue after all. I disabled printers in VMWare’s virtual machine’s settings, and lo and behold, the problem (seems to have) disappeared. VMWare must have been trying to get printing to work.

Answer (score 2):

a) Removing cups doesn't actually remove CUPS.

b) you want to use `apt-get purge` not remove, probably.

You want to purge this lot, at a minimum. You can do it with a wildcard or regex.

```
apt-get purge '^cups'
```

seems to delete all packages beginning with cups, but really we want all files containing cups. Regex experts to the rescue, please. :-) See `apt-get purge '^cups'` output below.

(UPDATE: Per Paul's comments below, GNOME apparently insists on having some CUPs libraries installed, so I suggested he just remove frontend stuff, so in fact maybe he really does want `apt-get purge '^cups'`).

```
$ dpkg -l | grep cups
ii  brhl4070cdw-cups-ppd                 1.0.0-1                              Brother HL-4070CDW CUPS driver
ii  cups                                 1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - server
ii  cups-bsd                             1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - BSD commands
ii  cups-client                          1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - client programs (SysV)
ii  cups-common                          1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - common files
ii  cups-pdf                             2.5.0-16                             PDF printer for CUPS
ii  cups-ppdc                            1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD manipulation utilities
ii  cupsys                               1.3.8-1+lenny8                       Common UNIX Printing System (transitional package)
ii  cupsys-bsd                           1.3.8-1+lenny8                       Common UNIX Printing System (transitional package)
ii  cupsys-client                        1.3.8-1+lenny8                       Common UNIX Printing System (transitional package)
ii  cupsys-common                        1.3.8-1+lenny8                       Common UNIX Printing System (transitional package)
ii  libcups2                             1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library
ii  libcups2-dev                         1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Development files CUPS library
ii  libcupscgi1                          1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - CGI library
ii  libcupsdriver1                       1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Driver library
ii  libcupsimage2                        1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Raster image library
ii  libcupsmime1                         1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - MIME library
ii  libcupsppdc1                         1.4.4-7                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD manipulation library
ii  libcupsys2                           1.3.8-1+lenny8                       Common UNIX Printing System (transitional package)
ii  libcupsys2-dev                       1.3.8-1+lenny8                       Common UNIX Printing System (transitional package)
ii  libgnomecups1.0-1                    0.2.3-3+b1                           GNOME library for CUPS interaction

# apt-get  -s purge '^cups'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'cupsys-client' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-client' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-pdf' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-pk-helper' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-bsd' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-common' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-pt' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-dbg' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-ppdc' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsddk' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups-driver-gutenprint' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsddk-drivers' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsomatic-ppd' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsys-driver-gutenprint' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsys-bsd' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsys-common' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cupsys' for regex '^cups'
Note, selecting 'cups' instead of 'cupsddk-drivers'
Package cups-pk-helper is not installed, so not removed
Package cups-driver-gutenprint is not installed, so not removed
Package cups-dbg is not installed, so not removed
Package cupsddk is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cups* cups-bsd* cups-client* cups-common* cups-pdf* cups-ppdc* cupsys* cupsys-bsd* cupsys-client* cupsys-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 10 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Purg cupsys [1.3.8-1+lenny8]
Purg cups-pdf [2.5.0-16]
Purg cups [1.4.4-7]
Purg cupsys-bsd [1.3.8-1+lenny8]
Purg cups-bsd [1.4.4-7]
Purg cupsys-client [1.3.8-1+lenny8]
Purg cups-client [1.4.4-7]
Purg cupsys-common [1.3.8-1+lenny8]
Purg cups-ppdc [1.4.4-7]
Purg cups-common [1.4.4-7]
```

Comment: “Removing cups doesn't actually remove CUPS.” — aha, okay, gotcha. I should also have mentioned, I do use the GUI from time to time, it’s not a purely headless server. Are any of these packages related to it?

Comment: @Paul: Related to what?

Comment: @Faheem: ah sorry — the GUI, Gnome.

Comment: @ Paul: These packages are all related to CUPs. They should not affect GNOME, except insofar as GNOME has CUPS functionality. In any case, I recommend always running `apt-get` with the `-s` test option, just to be safe, and carefully check what packages it is proposing to remove.

Comment: @Faheem: sure, will do. I think running `apt-get purge` on `libcups2` seemed to remove Gnome and a bunch of other stuff from my system, as Gnome doesn’t seem to be there any more. No worries though, this is all in a VM, so it‘s easy to restore. (And this is why, as you say, one should actually read the long list of packages `apt-get` says it’s going to remove!)

Comment: @Paul: Ok, in that case, you can leave libcups alone. Your problem probably stems from the frontend programs, ie everything starting with cups. So `apt-get  -s purge '^cups'` may actually be your best bet. Sorry, I think I mentioned -s above, but then erased it.

Comment: @Faheem: gotcha — probably a couple of front-end programs with print dialogs. Cool cool, many thanks for your help — I’ll have a fiddle and see what works.